# In d3.js , Is there any way to get the path length at particular point?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am new to d3.js , I can find that d3 api provides the way to get the svg point at particular length via method `getPointAtLength(l)` but i am looking for a way to calculate the the path length at specific point in d3?

Please share your suggestion if any.

Answer (score 5):

There's no *simple* way to do this, like the SVG `getPointAtLength` method. However it is easy to get the total length of a `path` using `getTotalLength()`.

Given that, the option I would suggest is to draw a new path, that follows the existing path up to the new point.

This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/b4bbgdnz/5/

Hovering the mouse over a selected point on the existing thin black path causes a 'sub-path' to be drawn (in red) up to the selected point. The text below shows the selected coordinates and the length of the path *from (0,0), the first point* to it.

[image: showing path and sub path for length calculations]

Here I assume that points along the `x` axis are ordered, so that when I get the mouseover x-value from the event handler, I know that any points where x is lower than this value should be inculded in the sub-path. I add these points, plus the mouseover point coords, to a new array from which the sub-path will be created:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pathData[0].length; i++) {
    var coord = pathData[0][i];
    if ((coord.x <= mouse_coord.x)) {
        subPathData[0].push(coord);
    }
}

subPathData[0].push(mouse_coord);
```

Then I calculate the length of the subpath:

```
subpath_length = d3.select(".subpath")[0][0].getTotalLength();
```

### A note on interpolation

The approach works when not using [line interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate). However it will fail if you replace, for example, `.interpolate("none");` with `.interpolate("monotone");` in the jsfiddle. That's because the sub-path won't follow the full path correctly in some cases, like this:

[image: showing how this method fails with interpolation]

A solution that always worked on interpolated lines would probably be a lot more complicated